# How to build using MSBuild and Delphi XE2

Tags: delphi, msbuild, delphi-xe2

I've been building projects using Delphi XE and MSBuild using the following simple example which works fine in a batch file. Project1 is an empty project created using 'File | New | VCL forms application in the IDE:

```
call "c:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\8.0\bin\rsvars.bat"
msbuild.exe /target:Build /p:config=Release  "c:\scratch\test\project1.dproj" 
pause
```

If I created a new empty project in Delphi XE2, save it as project1.dproj (the dproj is VERY different from XE) and run the following:

```
call "c:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0\bin\rsvars.bat"
msbuild.exe /target:Build /p:config=Release  "c:\scratch\test\project1.dproj" 
pause
```

It gives:

```
Build FAILED.

"c:\scratch\test\project7.dproj" (Build target) (1) ->
  c:\scratch\test\project7.dproj : error MSB4057: The target "Build" does not e
xist in the project.

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.00
```

I've tried various target names including things I find in Codegear.Delphi.Targets but I dont know wnough about MSBuild. Can anyone help with what I should put please?

LATER RESOLUTION: This was tried on another PC with XE2 and it works ok as suggested by David below. In fact the problem was the content of the RSVARS.BAT file which did not specify the BDS path correctly.

Comment: Its this line in your dproj file? : <Import Condition="Exists('$(BDS)\Bin\CodeGear.Delphi.Targets')" Project="$(BDS)\Bin\CodeGear.Delphi.Targets"/>

Your msbuild.exe command is ok and working fine here.

Comment: That's how I do it. Something is up with your installation. You need to talk to Emba.

Comment: @Arjen: Yes, I have that in the dproj file.

Comment: @David: You are right - tried this on another machine with XE2 and it works fine so it must be an installation issue. Thanks.

Comment: You should post an answer to your own question and mark it as accepted.

Comment: @BrianFrost out of interest, when you create the new project does it only have the Win32 platform in the list, or Win64 and/or OSX (in the case of FireMonkey) as well?

Comment: @BrianFrost You should move your resolution to an answer, add the steps you used to troubleshoot and then mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As reported by the OP, the issue was an incorrect BDS path in the RSVARS.bat file.